# Lock timer doesn't work for answers

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, locked-questions

When a diamond moderator locks a question, there's a choice to have it auto-unlock in an hour, a day, a week, or not at all. Generally, this function works fine.

However, I locked every post on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17860/whats-the-difference-between-bucket-and-pail/) for an hour, and while the question auto-unlocked an hour later, I had to manually unlock the answers. I doubt it's a cron issue because the question was the last thing I locked, so if it unlocked, everything else should have as well.

Furthermore, the lock box displayed a "Unlocks in xx minutes" note (visible to mods only, I think) on the question lock, but not on any of the answer locks.

On that basis, I'm pretty sure the timer lock on answers doesn't work. If it's supposed to work, please fix it; if there's supposed to be no timer at all, please make it work nonetheless, because it would be incredibly useful in situations like this.

Comment: I'd noticed the timer not appearing when I locked an answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, it's confusing.

Earlier today I locked an answer but I didn't remember if I had set for how long (the default is one hour). There was no countdown in the post notice and no indication in the history regarding how long the lock was *supposed* to be for. After an hour had passed and the post remained locked, I went looking for information and found this question. I assumed that the lock would be permanent, since it hadn't expired after an hour.

Just now, I went back to the question to find that the answer had been unlocked (by Community) just a minute or two shy of two hours after it had been locked. So, *something* is releasing the lock after *some* amount of time but there's no indication to anyone (moderator or otherwise) whether the lock is temporary or permanent and, if temporary, how temporary.

As the question suggests, having a timer or at least **some** indicator (in the history, perhaps) of how long the lock is/was set for, would be really helpful, even if the timer isn't exact. Since only one moderator knows the expiration time choice (hour, day, week, permanent), that means that they have to convey the information to the other mods if they want to know when to expect it to expire. Having it appear in the history or on the post makes it clear.

Comment: It would also be nice if the revision history explicitly stated that it was being unlocked due to an expiry, rather than just showing that it was "unlocked by Community" with no indication.

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324212/temporary-locks-on-answers-not-showing-lock-duration