# Temporary locks on answers not showing lock duration

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, moderator-tools, locked

Tested on Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow Meta and Pets.

### Questions

Temporary locks on questions are showing the duration (mod only).

Stack Overflow.
[image]

Meta Stack Overflow.
[image]

Pets.
[image]

### Answers

On answers they are not and there's no way to find the lock duration when we use timeline tools to examine the post.

Pets.
[image]

Stack Overflow.
[image]

Meta Stack Overflow.
[image]

Is this something that hasn't been implemented or is it a bug?

If it hasn't been implemented can we please have it implemented?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like this is no-longer reproducible with the modified display of close reasons and post notices.

Tested on [Computational Science Meta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/572/20688):

[image]

The notice seems to display the lock of the duration correctly.